# Integer и Int разница в чем?

Tags: java

`Integer` – это обьект (как `String`) и, соответственно, ему выделяется больше памяти, чем постоянному типу `int`. Использую перегрузку методов, метод принимает аргумент `Integer` а подаю ему `int`. Может ли возникнуть проблема?

Comment: Только не «пере**за**грузку», а «перегрузку методов». А у вас есть существенные причины использовать Integer вместо int?

Comment: У меня нет .Попался в руки Исходник ,там перегрузка методов принимает интеджер а подается ему инт ,немогу понять смысл этого ведь чисто логически ты даешь больше памяти тому что ненужно .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Integer` – это объектный тип, `int` – это примитивный тип.

`Integer` – это объектная оболочка над `int`.

> Использую перегрузку методов, метод принимает аргумент Integer, а подаю ему int. Может ли возникнуть проблема?

Если Вы используете *перегрузку методов* и, например, метод `doIt(...)` имеет две сигнатуры:

```
public void doIt(int i) {...}
```

и

```
public void doIt(Integer i) {...}
```

то при вызове `doIt(5)` будет вызван первый метод, а при `doIt(new Integer(5))` – второй.

Если же у Вас есть только метод

```
public void doIt(Integer i) {...}
```

то при вызове `doIt(5)` проблем не будет, так как значение `5` автоматически упакуется (*autoboxing*) в `Integer`.

Comment: Спасибо все четко !